# Setup VPN in complex setup

Tags: networking, server, vpn

Let me describe you my situation.

I have an old laptop, which has Ubuntu 12.04 installed positioned central in my house. This laptop is connected to my AirPort Extreme. The latter is (by wire) connected to my providers router (it's called *bbox* and this box has the incoming landline).

I've connected my NAS to the Ubuntu laptop by so it serves as file server within my local network. By so, I can connect to my Ubuntu laptop from my iPhone and my MacBook Pro.

The AirPort Extreme gives static IP's to my Ubuntu laptop (10.0.1.99), my iPhone (10.0.1.88) and my Mac (10.0.1.77). With this setup, I can connect and browse to my Ubuntu files (mostly movies and TV-shows).

But I would like to browse through my files from outside my network as well (in my car, in my office,...). So I thought a VPN would bring the solution. I've followed many guides and tutorials (mostly about openvpn2), but I cannot make this setup work.

Are there any practical how-to guides in my situation? Or anyone who can tell me what to install on what device?

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Some ISP Routers already provide a VPN Server. Did you check for that?
If it doesnt you need to NAT port 1194 UDP to your Ubuntu Notebook and install a OpenVPN Server on it.

Then install TinyCA to create a certificate authority and the certificates/keys.

This is the general idea. If I had more time I could make screenshots and stuff but you should be able to google all this.

Hope this helps a little bit.